# Can we get core id on which the process is running in MPI?

Tags: linux, gcc, operating-system, mpi

I have developed MPI program which can execute [matrix multiplication](http://www.just4tech.com/2013/10/matrix-multiplication-in-mpi.html) on different cores in distributed environment and I can demonstrate the execution on different nodes by getting hostname of the node. But when we are running program on single node can I get core id which demonstrate the execution on multiple node sample code is given below

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"mpi.h"

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
int size,rank;
int a,b,c;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if(rank==0)
{
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("insert a and b");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    MPI_Send(&b,1,MPI_INT,i+1,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&c,1,MPI_INT,i+1,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
} 

if(rank!=0)
{
MPI_Recv(&b,1,MPI_INT,0,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
MPI_Recv(&c,1,MPI_INT,0,6,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
a=b*c;
printf("Mul = %d\n",a);
//Print name of core on which my process is running
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get core id by using the sched_getcpu() function present in utmpx.h header file
sample program from net is shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include <utmpx.h>

int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
printf( "cpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu() );
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As its `man` page tells, `sched_getcpu` is Linux specific and is calling `getcpu` ....

Answer (score 5):

While it is possible to obtain the ID of the logical processor that currently executes the code, this often makes no sense unless you **enable MPI process binding**, also known as process pinning (in Intel's parlance). Binding (or pinning) restricts the CPU affinity set of each MPI process, i.e. the set of CPUs on which the process is allowed to execute. If the affinity set includes only a single logical CPU, then the process would only execute on that logical CPU. A logical CPU usually corresponds to a hardware thread on CPUs with SMT/hyperthreading or to a CPU core on non-SMT/non-hyperthreaded CPUs. Given affinity sets that include more than one logical CPUs, the scheduler is allowed to migrate the process around in order to keep the CPUs in the set equally busy. The default affinity set usually includes all available logical CPUs, that is the process could be scheduled for execution on any core or hardware thread.

Only when MPI process binding is in place and each process is bound to a single logical CPU it makes sense to actually query the OS for the location of the process. You have to consult your MPI implementation manual on how to enable it. For example, with Open MPI you would do something like:

```
mpiexec --bind-to-core --bycore -n 120 ...
```

`--bind-to-core` tells Open MPI to bind each process to a single CPU core and `--bycore` tells it to allocate cores consecutively on multisocket machines (that is, first to allocate all cores in the first socket, then in the second socket, etc.) With Intel MPI the binding (called *pinning* by Intel) is enabled by setting the environment variable `I_MPI_PIN` to `1`. The process placement strategy is controlled by the value of `I_MPI_PIN_DOMAIN`. To achieve the same as the above shown Open MPI command line, one would to the following with Intel MPI:

```
mpiexec -n 120 -env I_MPI_PIN 1 -env I_MPI_PIN_DOMAIN "core:compact" ...
```

To obtain the location of your processes in a platform-independent way, you could use [`hwloc_get_last_cpu_location()`](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.6.2/a00053.php#ga8e9a4b5ee3eaa18fd3a229790c6b5b17) from the [**hwloc** library](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.6.2/). It is developed as part of the Open MPI project but can be used as a stand-alone library. It provides an abstract interface to query the system topology and to manipulate the affinity of processes and threads. **hwloc** supports Linux, Windows and many other OSes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Linux specific [getcpu(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html) syscall (or, as [Krishna answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953666/841108), the Linux specific [sched_getcpu(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html) function wrapping it). Read carefully the man page (that `getcpu` syscall does not have any libc wrapper!). Notice that it may gives you some obsolete information (because the kernel can -and does- *migrate* processes or tasks -e.g. threads- at *any time* from one CPU core to another).

Otherwise, your *MPI* implementation is probably using threads or processes. You could query them with [gettid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) (which needs some wrapper)  for threads, or [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) for processes.

You may want to code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

static inline long my_gettid(void)
{ return syscall(SYS_gettid); }
```

and perhaps something similar for `getcpu`....

You could also use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. query `/proc/self/stat` (the 39<sup>th</sup> field gives the *processor* number)... Perhaps just displaying all of it is the simplest way:

```
{
   char line[128];
   FILE *fs = fopen("/proc/self/stat","r");
   if (!fs) { perror("/proc/self/stat"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   while (!feof(fs)) {
     memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
     fgets(line, sizeof(line), fs);
     fputs(line, stdout);
   };
   fclose(fs);
 }
```

Remember that the Linux kernel (its scheduler) is migrating tasks (i.e. processes or threads) from one CPU core to another one at any time. So querying that is next to useless (the task could have migrated between the moment you query it and the moment you display it).

Comment: my_gettid() function returns starting values randomly which increment by 1 such as 8732, 8733, 8734..... If I have two cores it should return value in between 0 and 1. I am not getting the significance of this increasing values

Comment: Please read the man page of `gettid`. It returns a thread id. If you just want the core number use `/proc/self/stat` (the *processor*  field) or `getcpu`. But be careful, the kernel can migrate a task between the moment you query its cpu and the moment you print it.

Comment: `getcpu()` is also a Linux-specific system call.